# What is the correct way to filter GraphQL queries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

For example, lets say that I make a call to graphQL as follows:

```
query {
          product {
            title
            description
            price
            path
          }
        }
```

This call returns back to me an array with 10 items but I only want 5 at random.  I currently have it setup to get the 10 then grab 5 randomly but I feel as GraphQL is still working too hard and if I had say 1000 items returned I would not need 995 of them.

I have seen queries like:

```
        query {
          product(limit:5) {
            title
            description
            price
            path
          }
        }
```

which would make it so only 5 items are returned no matter what.  My question is, is this handled within the resolver?

The way my resolver current looks is:

```
product: async () => {
    try {
    const products = await Product.find()

      return products.map(product => {
        return transformProduct(product);
      })
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Would it be correct to do something like:

```
product: async ({limit}) => {
    try {
    let products = await Product.find()
      if(limit) {
        products = getRandom(products, limit)
      }

      return products.map(product => {
        return transformProduct(product);
      })
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

I have now tested that this works, but I am concerned that GraphQL is still retrieving more data than it needs to be. Is this how apollo handles its "first" and "skip" variables or is it more efficient?

Comment: filtering is out of graphql specs..... read docs about resolver arguments - use argument to read DB, you didn't limited DB querying - you didn't filtered/limited queried array, too

Comment: As @xadm mentioned, you basically need to pass "limit" into your Product.find() so it handles only retrieving 5 from the db; perhaps with a "LIMIT 5" clause in SQL, assuming you also alter the SELECT to randomize. If you retrieve them all before throwing away most of them, you have poorly implemented the GraphQL filter.

Comment: Thats kind of what I thought I was doing and I just wanted to clarify that.  Thank you much both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to pass "limit" into your Product.find() so it handles only retrieving 5 from the db; perhaps with a "LIMIT 5" clause in SQL, assuming you also alter the SELECT to randomize. If you retrieve them all before throwing away most of them, you have poorly implemented the GraphQL filter